# How can I access history list? (python)

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I want to be able to track if history changed by waiting for its last element to change from modal operator. Is there a way to access such list over python?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot access the history list directly from python (I'm pretty confident this is the case.).

The history list is called by `bpy.ops.ed.undo_history()` and doesn't have any accessible attributes that you can read into a list. In fact, `bpy.ops.ed`'s methods come from `bpy.types` where the class  starts with `ED_OT_` (eg. `bpy.ops.ed.undo()` is really an instance of `bpy.types.ED_OT_undo()`

It looks like the undo stuff is in the guts of blender-app.exe but you can try and mess around with this bpy.ops.ed stuff and see if you can manage something that I may be overlooking.